# Can we programatically choose which SIM(from dual) to send SMS from?

Tags: ios, swift, dual-sim

I am using MFMessageComposeViewController for loading SMS content.
But it takes the default number for sending the SMS.

Can I change the default number programatically like,
Choose
Sim 1
or
Sim 2

from within the app without depending on iPhone settings?

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D came to know that its not possible to choose the network(sim) within the app.

But once the message screen is shown you'll be using the default number which you have configured on your device for SMS.